# any difference in dataframe between load from CSV and created by pd.DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to add a column based on an condition in each row.

```
type=['A','B']
df['color'] = ''
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['product'] in type:
        row['color'] = 'Green'
    else:
        row['color'] = 'Blue'
```

it works fine with a dataframe created by pd.DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'product': ['A','C','C','D','A','B','C','A'], 
                   'price': ['10','20','30','40','10','20','30','40'],
                   'sales': ['20','-','60','-','20','-','60','-']
                  })
```

```
product price sales  color
0       A    10    20  Green
1       C    20     -   Blue
2       C    30    60   Blue
3       D    40     -   Blue
4       A    10    20  Green
5       B    20     -  Green
6       C    30    60   Blue
7       A    40     -  Green
```

However, it doesn't work with a dataframe loaded from a csv file

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\xxx14\Documents\Python Scripts\test.csv')
df
```

```
product price   sales
0   A   10  20
1   C   20  -
2   C   30  60
3   D   40  -
4   A   10  20
5   B   20  -
6   C   30  60
7   A   40  10
```

After iterate each row, nothing added in the column `color`

```
  product  price sales color
0       A     10    20      
1       C     20     -      
2       C     30    60      
3       D     40     -      
4       A     10    20      
5       B     20     -      
6       C     30    60      
7       A     40    10
```

I am curious to know why?

Answer (score 0):

I not sure why those are different for you; however you should avoid looping over a dataframe. You logic can be simplified to

```
import numpy as np

df['color'] = np.where(df['product'].isin(['A', 'B']), 'Green', 'Blue')
```

```
  product price sales  color
0       A    10    20  Green
1       C    20     -   Blue
2       C    30    60   Blue
3       D    40     -   Blue
4       A    10    20  Green
5       B    20     -  Green
6       C    30    60   Blue
7       A    40     -  Green
```